# post_type argument not working correctly with WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to filter posts based on the post type. If I add filter `post_type => 'page'`, there will be posts included instead of pages. What would be the problem? The `meta_key` argument does not work either. I have [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) plugin installed. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$args = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_key'      => 'top-story', // true-false
    'meta_value'    => '1'
    ));

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$args` array should not have the call to `get_posts()`. `$args` should just be an array:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_key'      => 'top-story', // true-false
    'meta_value'    => '1'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Happy to help, @lingo!